# Rails routes for get request with query params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, restful-url

I need a route to accept a request `reports#show` with an attached `:query` parameter and I can't figure out how to write it. It needs to respond to this link in my view:

```
= link_to report_path(query: params[:query]) do
```

config/routes.rb

```
  resources :reports do
    resources :chapters
    resources :pages
  end
```

Tried variations of: `get '/reports/:id/:query', :as => 'reports_query'` but I keep getting:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"reports", :query=>"europe"}
```

Project is mostly RESTful but I'll take anything that works at this point. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You should define your route to query with code like this

```
# routes.rb
resources :reports do
  get ':query', to: 'reports#show', on: :member, as: :query
end
```

It will generate path helper you can use that way

```
= link_to 'Query Report', query_report_path(@report, query)
```

Comment: that "works", perfectly it would seem(rake routes): `query_report GET  /reports/:id/:query(.:format)   reports#show`. though I think my `link_to` helper is what's broken... `= link_to report_path(query: params[:query]) do` is giving me that `No route matches...` error(above). Any ideas how to create that link_to and add include the `:query` param? It needs to be a block and that's what's got me tied up...

Comment: You can get access to `params` hash only from you controller (and then pass it to view in variable if you need).

Comment: Ya, that's how I plan to handle it when it comes in (and did the first time through) but I need to pass it along through this `link_to` tag but not sure of syntax?!?

Comment: Syntax is simple as you could see: `link_to 'Link Text', query_report_path(@report, query)` – where `query` is your query param

Comment: Yeah, but in this cast the link_to is a block (no 'Link' text and it ends with `do`) so order of args is tripping me up.

Comment: Like this `link_to query_report_path(@report, query) do 'Link Text or other html content'; end`

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same problem here, and I solved it using the [`default`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults) param while defining my routes.

`get :twitter_form, defaults: { form: "twitter" }, as: :twitter_form, to: "campaigns#show"`